# How to create subtitle files and add them to a video?

Tags: video-editing, subtitles

How can I generate a .srt or .sub file and add it to a video?

Comment: Are you planning to type the subtitles yourselve or rip them from a DVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make subtitles I recommend [Subtitle Workshop](http://www.urusoft.net/home.php?lang=1). You can try the version 4 beta although I don't miss anything in version 2.51.

I have also heard good things about [Aegisub](http://blog.aegisub.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Search for a program called Subrip.  It's a bit old, but still works.